# past and present

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

It's written in an advertisement of a mobile operator.

- The plan was specially made for you.
- The plan is specially made for you.

Which one is proper to use in an advertisement? I felt a little awkward while reading the first sentence.

Comment: It depends on whether the "plan" *was* or *will be* made, relative to the time when you would contact them. It could be either.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is just fine, and I believe it would be more correct, although the second could be reworked this way to also be correct:

> The plan has been specially made for you.

If you prefer the present tense, you could say:

> The plan is intended specially for you.

Or something like that. If you say "is made" it implies something ongoing. You could say that about a burger that is made when someone orders it ("The burger is made specially for you"), but not really for something that is actually made ahead of time.